# Win CMD: How to simply copy a folder without typing name twice?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

I have a folder with a few files:

```
- folder1
    file1
    file2
```

And want to copy it folder some `folder2`. Expecting following structure:

```
- folder2
    - folder1
        file1
        file2
```

I could do:

```
xcopy /I /E folder1 folder2\folder1
```

But is there a way to **avoid duplicating the folder name** `folder1`? A command saying: "put this folder (as is) to there"? Just as `(x)copy` works for files: `copy folder1\file1 folder2`. No need to type again `file1`.

I am looking for a Windows built-in tool usable from `cmd.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is because if the first argument (the "source") to `xcopy` (or `copy`, or `robocopy`) is a directory, it assumes that you want to copy the contents of that directory. So to get it to do what you want to do, you need to start your copy one level higher, and then it will treat Folder1 as a thing to be copied.

If Folder1 is the only thing in its parent directory, you can do it like this, from the directory containing Folder1. (Let's say that Folder1 is in `C:\Temp\CopyTest`.)

```
C:\Temp\CopyTest>xcopy * C:\Temp\Folder2 /E /I
```

Comment: And what if there are more folders next to `folder1`?

Comment: If there are other directories in the same place as Folder1, you're back to having to do `xcopy /I /E folder1 folder2\folder1`.